# Span not exported to Jaeger Collector using OpenTelemetry Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, open-telemetry

I have configured `JaegerGrpcSpanExporter` , so that it can export the created spans to Jaeger-Collector.

I don't want to export the spans to Jaeger-Agent. I have written down below code.

```
public BatchSpansProcessor getBatchSpanProcessor() { 
    return BatchSpansProcessor.newBuilder( 
        JaegerGrpcSpanExporter.newBuilder().setServiceName("collector-exporter"). setChannel(ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(localhost,14268).usePlaintext(). build()
    ).build();
}
```

when i change the port to 14250 i.e. Jaeger-agent port spans are exported to UI but with 14268 I am not able to find any trace at Jaeger UI.

Do i need to change the above code?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it after configuring port as 14250 as JaegerGrpcSpanExporter internally uses grpc port which has been configured to 14250 for jaeger-collector